# Process exited with return value 3221225477 accessing multi dimensional vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I can't find the problem in a c++ project i'm developing for educational purposes.
Here i will post my code and explain where I found the problem is (thanks to some debugging), i just can't figure out why this is a problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "<--------------- MATRIXES --------------->\n";
    // Dimensions
    const int HEIGHT = 3;
    const int WIDTH = 4;
    // Multi-dimensional int array
    int A[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {
        {0, 1, 2, 4},
        {1, 0, 2, 1},
        {1, 1, 5, 8}
    };
    // Multi-dimensional int vector built with data from A
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Am(HEIGHT);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
        Am[i].resize(WIDTH);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
            Am[i][j] = A[i][j];
    // Everything before this comment works fine

    // WORKING constructor for my Matrix
    Matrix<int> M(Am);

    // The problem is in the M.toString() call,
    // in the next code block i will explain exatcly where
    cout << "Matrix M:\n" << M.toString() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This is the main.cpp of my project, here is the Matrix.h file:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template <class T>
class Matrix{

    std::vector<std::vector<T> > M;
    int HEIGHT;
    int WIDTH;

    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T> > m) {
            HEIGHT = m.size();
            WIDTH = m[0].size();
            std::vector<std::vector<T> > M(HEIGHT);
            for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
                    M[i].push_back(m[i][j]);
        };

        std::string toString() {

            std::cout << M[0][0];
            std::string r = "";
            /*for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
                    if (j != WIDTH - 1)
                        r += std::to_string(M[i][j]) + " ";
                }
                if (i != HEIGHT - 1)
                    r += "\n";
            }*/
            return r;
        }
};
```

The code would be larger but i commented everything which is not in this post, as you can see the toString method only prints M[0][0] an returns "", the executions "stops working" exactly at the std::cout << M[0][0], and i figured out that no matter where but when i try to access the multi dimensional vector M it stops working and it gives me: "Process exited with return value 3221225477".

Any ideas?

PS: I'm working on Windows 10, i have the same issue using clang and dev-c++
EDIT: It looks like the Matrix gets constructed (I already tested it, it gets constructed properly) but then the program forgets how the matrix is and trying to access it is like trying to access an empty vector... Don't know why..

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Questions like "why doesn't this work?" must come with a [mcve], lest they be considered off-topic.

Comment: Your constructor body has `std::vector<std::vector<T> > M(HEIGHT);` which defines a new `M` and shadows the member `M` for the rest of the constructor. Beyond that point you are always operating on that local `std::vector`. By the end of your constructor, your actual member `M` is still empty.

Comment: Do not record your width and height separarelt, just rely on your `std::vector`'s size and it's elements' size.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this is my first post on stackoverflow (i have followed it since ages) but this looks Minimal (I commented everything else), complete (the code doesn't need anything else to work) and veirifable (as it is it produces my exact problem) how could it be better?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux i got your point, now i try those adjustments, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Davide, `AVector.h` is missing. Also, there is probably no need to have more than one file at all, just copy'n'paste the two header files into main.cpp, then keep removing stuff (e.g. the template around Matrix) until there is nothing left to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor to

```
Matrix(std::vector<std::vector<T> > const & m) : M(m) {}
```

This will resolve the shadowing problem too. Also you can remove HEIGHT and WIDTH from your Matrix class.

This fixes the problem in two ways. First it resolves the **shadowing** issue in the original definition of the constructor since a local variable has the same name, `M`, shadows the class member, `M`. Second, it initializes the class member `M` directly by `m` without **redundant copies** existing in the original definition.

The main file can look like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "<--------------- MATRIXES --------------->\n";

    vector<vector<int> > Am { { 1, 1, 1 },
                              { 2, 2, 3 },
                              { 6, 7, 8 } };
    Matrix<int> M(Am);

    cout << "Matrix M:\n" << M.toString() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux could you be more specific?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you think I should use pass-by-reference in the constructor? May you send me in private a modified version of my constructor that you think is more optimal? I'm quite new to C++ and coming from a Python environment it gives me some headaches...

Comment: I changed the constructor to use a const ref. The rvalue one can be added separately but it does not directly related to this problem.

Comment: @CSPei I guess you're right. Seems like it wasn't so far off after all. Edit : An explanation of why this fixes the problem would complete this answer.

Comment: May you also post the changed  main.cpp with the call at the constructor by reference, please?

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciated!